# Some dots are not active when hovered in area chart using recharts

Tags: recharts

I am using recharts to render an area chart and I realize that if there are more than two points that are on the same x axis, the points in the middle (except for the largest y-value and smallest y-value) don't become active when hovered.

Below is my code for demonstration:

```
import { ResponsiveContainer, AreaChart, Area, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Label, Tooltip } from "recharts"


const topMargin = 10;
const leftMargin = 3;
const bottomMargin = 20;
const rightMargin = 15;

const data = [
    {
        x: 1,
        y: 2
    },
    {
        x: 2,
        y: 3,
    },
    {
        x: 2,
        y: 4,
    },
    {
        x: 2,
        y: 5
    },
    {
        x: 3,
        y: 4
    }
]

export default function Test() {
    return (
        <div style={{ width: '33vw', height: '30vh' }}>
            <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                <AreaChart
                    data={data}
                    margin={{
                        top: topMargin,
                        left: leftMargin,
                        bottom: bottomMargin,
                        right: rightMargin,
                    }}
                >
                    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                    <XAxis
                        dataKey="x"
                        axisLine={{ stroke: "black" }}
                        tick={{ fill: "black" }}
                        tickLine={{ stroke: "black" }}
                        domain={[1, 3]}
                        style={{ fontSize: "14px" }}
                        type="number"
                    >
                        <Label
                            value="x"
                            position="insideBottom"
                            style={{ textAnchor: "middle", fontSize: "14px" }}
                            fill="black"
                            fontWeight="bold"
                            dy={bottomMargin}
                        />
                    </XAxis>
                    <YAxis
                        dataKey="y"
                        axisLine={{ stroke: "black" }}
                        tick={{ fill: "black" }}
                        tickLine={{ stroke: "black" }}
                        style={{ fontSize: "14px" }}
                        domain={[2, 5]}
                        type="number"
                    >
                        <Label
                            value="y"
                            position="insideLeft"
                            angle={-90}
                            fill="black"
                            fontWeight="bold"
                            style={{ textAnchor: "middle", fontSize: "14px" }}
                        />
                    </YAxis>
                    <Tooltip />
                    <Area
                        type="linear"
                        dataKey="y"
                        stroke="#7ABFFF"
                        fill="rgba(0, 133, 255, 0.13)"
                        dot={{ fill: "#90CAFF", stroke: "#90CAFF", fillOpacity: 1, r: 3 }}
                        activeDot={{
                            fill: "#0085FF",
                            stroke: "#0085FF",
                            fillOpacity: 1,
                            r: 3,
                        }}
                    >
                    </Area>
                </AreaChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Below is a gif to demonstrate the issue:
[screen recording gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaICp.gif)

I found out that if I use scatter chart, every point can be active when hovered, including all those on the same x axis. As much as I'd like to use scatter chart as a hack here, it couldn't fill the area which is a crucial feature I want.